# Reset/increase numbering after blank row in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I'm a beginner in Vb.net so please bear with me on my knowledge :) The format of the winform application I am developing now is from Excel, which users key in daily as below:

No | Piece    |  Qty  | Tube | Sub Total

1  |  ABC123  |  10.4 |   1    |
2  |  ABC456  |  10.3 |   1    |
3  |  ABC789  |  10.1 |   1    |   30.8

(blank row)

1  | ABC012   |  10.9 |   2    |
2  | ABC234   |  10.2 |   2    |
3  | ABC765   |  10.4 |   2    |
4  | ABC876   |  10.8 |   2    |   42.3

(blank row)

1  | ABC567   |  10.6 |   3    |   10.6

Grand total: 83.7

In excel, there are formulas to:

- reset numbering after blank row

- increase tube number by 1 after blank row

Both numbering and tube ID are auto populated.

Data is keyed in by user. User will purposely skip a row (blank) to put in "Piece" and automatically the "Tube" will be increased by 1. At the same time, "Subtotal" will be auto calculated as well.

Honestly I haven't tried anything because I am so clueless on where to start! This is definitely not the usual way of entering data using Datagridview >_<

My questions are, is this doable with Datagridview? Can users key in this way, with the blank row and subtotal? If no, is there any alternative in doing so? Thank you!

Comment: How Will data be input to datagridview? When Will blank rows be inserted? When Will subtotal be calculated?

Comment: Sorry I missed this point in my question. Data is keyed in by user. User will purposely skip a row (blank) to put in "Piece" and automatically the "Tube" will be increased by 1. At the same time, "Subtotal" will be auto calculated as well.

Comment: I have edited the question to include how data is keyed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Just Sample (no validation input), you must have 1 DataGridView (myDGV) with five columns (No, Piece, Qty, Tube and SubTotal), 2 textbox (txtPiece,txtQty) and 2 buttons (btnAdd, btnSkip):

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    myDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = False
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim myNextNo As Integer = 0
    Dim myNextTube As Integer = 0
    If myDGV.RowCount = 0 Then
        myDGV.Rows.Add(1, txtPiece.Text, txtQty.Text, 1, "")
    Else
        Dim myCnt As Integer = myDGV.RowCount
        If myDGV.Item(0, myCnt - 1).Value Is "" Then
            myNextNo = 1
            myNextTube = Integer.Parse(myDGV.Item(3, myCnt - 2).Value.ToString) + 1
        Else
            myNextNo = Integer.Parse(myDGV.Item(0, myCnt - 1).Value.ToString) + 1
            myNextTube = Integer.Parse(myDGV.Item(3, myCnt - 1).Value.ToString)
        End If
        myDGV.Rows.Add(myNextNo, txtPiece.Text, txtQty.Text, myNextTube, "")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnSkip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSkip.Click
    If myDGV.RowCount = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Can't skip, No Data")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If myDGV.Item(0, myDGV.RowCount - 1).Value Is "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Can't More skip, No Data")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim mySub As Long = 0
    For myCnt As Integer = myDGV.RowCount To 1 Step -1
        If myDGV.Item(0, myCnt - 1).Value Is "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        mySub += Long.Parse(myDGV.Item(2, myCnt - 1).Value.ToString)
    Next
    myDGV.Item(4, myDGV.RowCount - 1).Value = mySub
    myDGV.Rows.Add("", "", "", "", "")

End Sub
```

if you want to get grand total you can change btnSkip_Click procedure as bellow:

```
Private Sub btnSkip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSkip.Click
    If myDGV.RowCount = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Can't skip, No Data")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If myDGV.Item(0, myDGV.RowCount - 1).Value Is "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Can't More skip, No Data")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim mySub As Long = 0
    Dim myGrand As Long = 0
    Dim myStts As Boolean = False
    For myCnt As Integer = myDGV.RowCount To 1 Step -1
        If myDGV.Item(0, myCnt - 1).Value Is "" Then
            myStts = True
        End If
        Dim mySubTtl As Long = 0
        If myStts = False Then mySub += Long.Parse(myDGV.Item(2, myCnt - 1).Value.ToString)
        Long.TryParse(myDGV.Item(2, myCnt - 1).Value.ToString, mySubTtl)
        myGrand += mySubTtl
    Next
    myDGV.Item(4, myDGV.RowCount - 1).Value = mySub
    If myDGV.ColumnCount = 6 Then myDGV.Columns.Remove(myDGV.Columns(5))
    myDGV.Columns.Add("GrandTotal", "Grand Total")
    myDGV.Item(5, myDGV.RowCount - 1).Value = myGrand
    myDGV.Rows.Add("", "", "", "", "")

End Sub
```

Comment: This works wonders! All I have to do now is to insert these data into database. Thank you so much!!